# How to switch front camera to rear camera in window's application

Tags: c#, winforms, camera, window, front-camera

I have worked on image capturing window application in c#. This application/ software capturing image from window tablet and other window devices. In the window tablets have  two camera like front and rear camera use switch during capturing image switch front to rear and as well.
    Any one have any solution please give me.

Thanlks

Comment: Do all Windows devices have front and rear cameras? Perhaps you need to enumerate them?